# Weak parallelogram law: proof of counter-example of this property

Tags: hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Consider the following weak parallelogram law:
$$ 2\left\lVert x \right\rVert^2 + 2\left\lVert y \right\rVert^2 \leq \left\lVert x+y \right\rVert^2 + \left\lVert x-y \right\rVert^2 \:. $$
Clearly this implies the following property:
$$ \left\lVert x+y \right\rVert^2 \:\text{and}\: \left\lVert x-y \right\rVert^2 \leq 1 \implies \left\lVert x \right\rVert^2 \:\text{or}\: \left\lVert y \right\rVert^2 \leq 1/2 \:. $$

> My question is "does this property imply the weak parallelogram law?".